# Plugin is not appearing in pending plugins

Tags: grails, plugins

I've developed the new plugin [likeable](https://github.com/turboDi/grails-likeable) and have filled the request [form](https://grails.org/plugins/submitPlugin), then I've got some kind of confirmation, refreshed the page and my plugin disappeared. 
Now I can't find it in [pending plugins](https://grails.org/plugins/pending) and can't submit it once again, because the plugin name was already taken by my lost plugin.
Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: [Here it is](https://grails.org/plugins/pending/453), still pending. I doubt there is a bug in paginating pending plugins page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approved it, so you should be all set. I also sent a small PR with some cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for approving and improving the plugin)